# Efficiently get PID's in certain ports from java

Tags: server, java, process, cpu-load, monitoring

I know `sudo lsof -t -i:{port}` will give the list of PID's involved in that port and I can run this command via java by `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` command. But the thing is I have thousands of thread running and every thread is executing this command with around 10s intervals which results in approximately 100+ total execution per second of this command alone which is taking a lot of server resources+time and load average is getting a rocket spike causing the program halt & crash.

What is the efficient way to do so in this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it anyway and I had to get PID from around all 65500 ports and save it in hashmap for later usage in the interval of around every 10 secs. I made it done within **2-2.1 secs** while **30,000 ports** were **active**.
I used "ps -aux" command for getting all active PID,PORT tuples at a time and then insert to hashmap after parsing (runtime parsing of command output and simultaneous insertion to hashmap).